# How to build a complete and safe file path when I have a directory path, a file name and an extension?

Tags: objective-c, ios, filesystems, nsstring

Assuming that directoryPath points to the Documents directory of the app:

```
NSString *fileName = @"demo";
NSString *extension = @"txt";
NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathExtension:extension];
```

I *THINK* that this is the way to do it, but I am not sure. Maybe there is an even better one. First I thought maybe I just create the file name with extension like this:

```
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", fileName, extension];
```

And then append it using `-stringByAppendingPathComponent:` , but I bet this is a bad idea for some reason. Maybe because it hard-codes the dot separator for extensions. They will never change this because it would be dump as hell. But you never know. So...

Did I do it the right way?

Need support for old OS versions.

Comment: Have you tried this, because it looks like this might work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
NSString* fileNameExt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", fileName, extension];
NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameExt];
```

Comment: The code in the question is safer than this (using `stringByAppendingPathExtension`). Granted, there's not much chance of either way going wrong, but it's better to use Apple's methods for working with paths than to write your own.

Comment: Yes I guess that this would do the job, but you're hardcoding the dot extension separator. Apple might decide one day that it has to be something different. Maybe some weird Unicode character. Who knows.